# Formatting ASP.NET Gridview Money Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following Column in my gridview

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
            DataFormatString="£{0:C2}" DataField="PriceBasePrice"
            HeaderText="Price you pay" ItemStyle-Width="120" />
```

The value being passed to the Column is 180.0

I thought that with:

```
       DataFormatString="£{0:C2}"
```

The Value would return as £180.00

but it returns as £180.0

Does anyone know what DataFormatString I should use ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to set the HtmlEncode attribute to false preventing the value being cast to a string first.

Alternatively you could just specify you're own format string:

```
DataFormatString="£{0:###,###,###.00}"
```

The # are empty until replaced with a value *if* one exists and the 0 are replaced with a value if one exists, otherwise they stay as 0.

Se Custom Numeric Format Strings - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you remove the 2, it should, by default, display the number with 2 decimal values.

```
{0:C}
```

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)